# MySql on Centos 7.2

Tags: mysql, centos-7

I have an issue with my MySql 5.7 version on my CentOS 7.2 instance
I installed MySql via the binaries.

```
groupadd mysql
useradd -r -g mysql -s /bin/false mysql
cd /usr/local
tar zxvf /path/to/mysql-VERSION-OS.tar.gz
ln -s full-path-to-mysql-VERSION-OS mysql
cd mysql
mkdir mysql-files
chown mysql:mysql mysql-files
chmod 750 mysql-files
bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql  ( it will generate  password for root user)
bin/mysqld --user=mysql  ( It will start the mysql)
```

3. Open another Session of Mysql . Go to /usr/local/mysql then enter root password recorded earlier

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

4. After mysql  Installation, I create a database "databaseDB"

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxx’;
CREATE USER mysql;
SET PASSWORD FOR mysql = PASSWORD ('yyyyy');
create database databaseDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
grant all on databaseDB.* to mysql@'%';
grant all on looker_tmp.* to mysql@'%';
flush privileges;
exit;
```

However, when I try to connect to the database as the root user:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

or the mysql user:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u mysql -p
```

I get the following socket error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I verified that the database is running:

```
[root@looker-mysql-automation-484606751-1-524514057 ~]# ps aux | grep mysql

root      18778  0.0  0.0 110528 12828 ?        Ss   02:47   0:00 /sbin/dhclient -H looker-mysql-automation-484606751-1-524514057 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--eth0.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0

mysql     80767  0.0  0.6 1183088 184448 pts/0  Sl+  13:21   0:04 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=mysql

root      87503  0.0  0.0 112652   972 pts/3    S+   15:24   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

I can connect to the database using:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Please add the command(s) you are trying that produce the error message: "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server..." It may be useful to know what you are doing.

Comment: When I try to connect as the root user

Comment: When I try to connect as the root user

Comment: added mysql commands that causes the socket error

Comment: It looks like you can connect when you add the option `-h 127.0.0.1`, is that correct? May I inquire: what's 'bad' about having to add the '-h' option?

Comment: is there a way around this not to have to specify localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: yes that is correct. Is there a way around having to specify localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: Yes, but honestly I've never done it. You would need to modify the `mysql.user` table probably. Above, you did `ALTER 'root'@'localhost'...`, you probably need to add another row where you add `'root'@'your_computers_hostname'`.

Comment: So, now I have enabled MySql to start via systemd: ```systemctl start mysqld -l```  However, now I'm running into the same problem that when specifying the localhost (127.0.0.1) I get the error: ```ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)``` when trying to connect as root. When trying to connect as mysql without the local host flag I get the error: ```ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)```

Comment: When starting the database using: ```./mysqld --user=mysql``` I can connect to the database again as mysql user. What is the difference in starting the database via systemd or using the ```./mysqld``` command manually?

Comment: I think what is happening when starting using systemd is mysql isn't actually running

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL instance is only listening in local interface, without the **unix socket** that we are used to connect most of the time.

**First** you should guarantee that your **mysqld** is starting with a valid `--socket` options, from command line or config file.

**Second**, and more strange, you should take care when installing something outside the repositories in any RedHat based system because SELinux will probrably complain about.

Verify if socket is really in `/tmp`, if not, find the socket:

```
find / -name 'mysql.sock'
```

And then **restorecon**:

```
restorecon /tmp/mysql.sock
```

This sould work. If you're in hurry, you can disable SELinux temporally:

```
setenforce=0
```

And try again.

There is a nice explanation here: https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/selinux-and-mysql